# Conditional operator

Tags: java

What is wrong in this code
`if(getResponseDataMap().containsKey("A"){
          a.setText(getResponseDataMap().get("A").toString);
}`

Converted like this .

`getResponseDataMap().containsKey("A")?a.setText(getResponseDataMap().get("A").toString()):""`

where getLocalRequestDataMap is a HashMap . And setText is function of android

It give compile time error 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to 
     boolean
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
    - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

Comment: does putting a bracket around the condition operation removes compile error?

Comment: add spaces.Maybe compiler think that "A"?"":"" is a single String

Comment: Show us the code around that. What do you do with the String returned by this expression? return it? Which type is returned by the method? Assign it to a variable? Which type is this variable? What's the type of the map? If you return empty string in all cases, what's the point of this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just on its own, the problem is that you've given an expression which isn't a statement.

With an assignment, however, it's fine:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String x = map.containsKey("A") ? "" : "";
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem is in some code you haven't shown. Please give more context - ideally a short but complete program like mine, but which demonstrates the error.

EDIT: Now that you've edited the question, you'll probably get a different error. The conditional operator isn't a valid stand-alone statement, and each of the operands needs to be a non-void expression (with some other caveats as well). So instead of this:

```
getResponseDataMap().containsKey("A") ?
    a.setText(getResponseDataMap().get("A").toString()):""
```

I *suspect* you want:

```
a.setText(getResponseDataMap().containsKey("A") ? 
          getResponseDataMap().get("A").toString() : null);
```

However, I would personally write this as:

```
Object response = getResponseDataMap().get("A");
a.setText(response == null ? "" : response.toString());
```

On the other hand, if you *only* want to set the text when the map contains the key, then you should go back to your original `if` statement, or possibly:

```
Object response = getResponseDataMap().get("A");
if (response != null) {
    a.setText(response.toString());
}
```

Comment: @MohitSharma: Edited my answer. It's unclear what you're trying to do, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same errors if I do nothing with the result of this expression. Here is an example:

```
    String try() {
      HashMap<String, String> getLocalRequestDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      getLocalRequestDataMap.containsKey("A")?"":"";
      return "";
    }
```

But if you do use it there are no errors:

```
    String try() {
      HashMap<String, String> getLocalRequestDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      return getLocalRequestDataMap.containsKey("A")?"":"";
    }
```

Comment: But again you should use the result of the ternary operator in some way. I don't think you can use it in the way you try to (this would work in c++, though)